# How to add annotation in mkmapview

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview, abpersonviewcontroller

I have  created a person object

```
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
```

I set the properties of person from my web services. `person` has all the properties set, like first name, last name, email id, phone number, address, url etc.

I want to load a map view, with multiple pins, where each particular pin holds the information about a particular person. On the click of each pin, I need to load the `ABPersonViewController` class of each person. I am not sure about how to add annotation with the information I have and how a particular pin could hold information about a particular person. 
In this case the person may or may not be in my address book, and I don't need to save the person in my address book . 
I am really confused about how to do this. Need help.

Edit:

I have 3 classes:

!. `Web service` class: where I have the person object.
2. `MapView` class: where I load the map view.
3. `Annotation` class: which has the details about my annotation.

How will I use person records and present it through `ABPersonViewController`. How should my `annotation` class be?

Comment: Where specifically is the confusion?  Do you have to store the person info in a ABPerson?  Maybe you can just create the ABPerson when you need to actually display the ABPersonViewController.  Though you should be able to create an annotation class with an ABPerson ivar.

Comment: Will storing `person` in `ABPerson` automatically save the `person` in the phone addressbook? In my case I dont need to save `person` in my addressbook, I just need to display the vCard of `person`, when I click a pin in the `mapview`

Comment: In the web service class, are you creating an ABPerson or do you have your own "Person" class?  I don't think just creating an ABPerson record in memory adds it to the address book.

Comment: I am not creating `ABPerson`, I just have the `person` record. I use `ABRecordSetValue` to set properties to `person`. Should I subclass `ABPerson` in this case. And how should my `annotation`class look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do to start is create a `Person` class (subclass of `NSObject`) that also implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol.  You could create two separate classes ("Person" and "PersonAnnotation") if you wanted to but it's not necessary.

In the `Person` class, you could either declare your own person-related properties such as First Name, Last Name, Email Address, etc. or you could just have an `ABRecordRef` ivar and let it store the individual fields for you.

I would only create an `ABPerson` record when I want to actually show the `ABPersonViewController` to keep the AB-specific code isolated and to manage the `ABPerson` record's creation and release more easily.  Regardless, just creating an `ABRecordRef` does not add it to the address book.  As the [ABPerson Reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) says:

> Person records don’t necessarily have to be stored in the Address Book
>   database. You can use person records as a way to group contact
>   information in memory and present it to the user through, for example,
>   a person view controller (ABPersonViewController).

So the `Person` class could look like this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *emailAddress;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@end


@implementation Person

@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;
@synthesize emailAddress;
@synthesize coordinate;

-(NSString *)title
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
}

-(NSString *)subtitle
{
    return emailAddress;
}

@end
```

The web service class would create an instance of `Person` and set the properties.  Then the map view class would add that instance directly to the map (since Person already implements MKAnnotation):

```
[mapView addAnnotation:person];
```

When the pin is tapped, the map view will call the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method.  Or, you could add a disclosure button to the annotation's callout in `viewForAnnotation` and respond to that in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method.

Whichever action method you decide to use, in that method you could then create an `ABRecordRef`, set its values from the annotation object, and then show the `ABPersonViewController`.  In both delegate methods, the `Person` annotation object could be retrieved using:

```
Person *personTapped = (Person *)view.annotation;
```

Comment: I have got one more question. How to pass `ABRecordref` as an arguement of a method.

Comment: In the [sample app ABUIGroups in GroupViewController.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ABUIGroups/Listings/Classes_GroupViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011307-Classes_GroupViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8), search for the `nameForSource` method for an example.

Comment: I get the following warning `Sending 'ABRecordRef' (aka 'const void *') to parameter of type 'ABRecordRef *' (aka 'const void **') discards qualifiers`

Comment: In the method argument, don't declare it as `(ABRecordRef *)`.  Just declare it as `(ABRecordRef)`.  Notice the method declaration in the sample app: `- (NSString *)nameForSource:(ABRecordRef)source`

Comment: OK. My bad. I tried to pass 'ABRecordRef' as an object. Now everything sorted.